# Custom Authorization policy with multiple requirements not working when applied to controller action

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, authorize-attribute

I have an .NET Core 3 WebAPI where I want to use custom policy-based authorization, where one of the policies has multiple requirements.

I have added the policy in `Startup.ConfigureServices()` and added `MyCustomPolicyHandler` to DI:

```
public virtual void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("MyCustomPolicy", policy =>
        {
            policy.Requirements.Add(new RequirementA());
            policy.Requirements.Add(new RequirementB());
            policy.Requirements.Add(new RequirementC());
            policy.Requirements.Add(new RequirementD());
            
        });
        
        services.AddScoped<IAuthorizationHandler, MyCustomPolicyHandler>();
        
    });                
}
```

I have implemented `MyCustomPolicyHandler` using the example from this documentation:
[Policy-based authorization in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

```
public class MyCustomPolicyHandler: IAuthorizationHandler
{

    public Task HandleAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context)
    {
    
        var pendingRequirements = context.PendingRequirements.ToList();         
        
        Console.WriteLine($"MyCustomPolicyHandler: {pendingRequirements.Count} requirements");
        
        foreach (var requirement in pendingRequirements)
        {
            if(requirement is RequirementA) {
            
                // do stuff to check the requirements
                context.Succeed(requirement);
                
            }
            else if(requirement is RequirementB) {
                
                // do stuff to check the requirements
                context.Succeed(requirement);
            
            }
            else if(requirement is RequirementC) {
            
                // do stuff to check the requirements
                context.Succeed(requirement);
                
            }
            else if(requirement is RequirementD) {
                
                // do stuff to check the requirements
                context.Succeed(requirement);
            
            }
        }
        
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    
    }
}
```

Next, I apply the policy to one of the controller actions:

```
public class MyController 
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Authorize(Policy="MyCustomPolicy")]    
    public ActionResult<SomeViewModel> Get(int id) {
    
        // do stuff
        
        return Ok(vm);
    }

}
```

The problem I'm encountering is there are no requirements associated with the policy.  The `Console.WriteLine()` message shows 0 requirements:

```
MyCustomPolicyHandler: 0 requirements
```

If I move the policy to the controller, the requirements are present:

```
[Authorize(Policy="MyCustomPolicy")]
public class MyController 
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<SomeViewModel> Get(int id) {
    
        // do stuff
        
        return Ok(vm);
    }

}
```

```
MyCustomPolicyHandler: 4 requirements
```

However, I need this policy applied to the action, not the controller.  The [Authorize(Policy="MyCustomPolicy")] attribute should work at the action level.

Any idea why this isn't working?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the place where `MyCustomPolicyHandler` is injected is misplaced. It needs to be placed outside of `AddAuthorization`.

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
     options.AddPolicy("MyCustomPolicy", policy =>
     {
         policy.Requirements.Add(new RequirementA());
         //...
     });          
});

services.AddScoped<IAuthorizationHandler, MyCustomPolicyHandler>();
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: good catch!   Do you mind showing me where you applied the policy (at controller or action?).  Unfortunately I'm still showing `pendingRequirements = 0`.

Comment: I put the policy on the action.